# FATAL EXCEPTION: main KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first time building an android application. However when i run the app on my Virtual Device, it stopped working and keeps crashing. The error says something about null pointer exception. This is my first time using Kotlin and I coded in Java and changed to Kotlin.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sales)

    val date: EditText? = null
    val changeDate: CheckBox? = null
    val yes: RadioButton? = null
    val no: RadioButton? = null

    date!!.setText("15-11-2017")
    date.isEnabled = false

    val button2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSubmit) as Button
    button2.setOnClickListener {
        var name = findViewById<View>(R.id.name) as EditText
        var cost = findViewById<View>(R.id.cost) as EditText
        val itemcost = Integer.parseInt(cost!!.text.toString())
        var price = findViewById<View>(R.id.price) as EditText
        val itemprice = Integer.parseInt(price!!.text.toString())
        var qty = findViewById<View>(R.id.quantity) as EditText
        var chgDate = false
        var discount = false
        val toast = Toast(applicationContext)
        if (itemprice < itemcost) {
            price!!.error = "Selling price cannot be lower than item price!"
        } else {
            if (changeDate!!.isChecked) {
                chgDate = true
                date.isEnabled = true
            }
            if (yes!!.isChecked) {
                discount = true
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@AddSales, "Item Name: " + name!!.text + "\n" + "Cost: " + cost!!.text + "\n" + "Item Price: " + price!!.text + "\n" + "Quantity: " + qty!!.text + "Date: " + date + "Staff Discount: " + discount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

and the error is:

> 11-17 06:23:34.603 3540-3540/com.example.ruiru.salestracker
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.ruiru.salestracker, PID: 3540
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ruiru.salestracker/com.example.ruiru.salestracker.AddSales}:
>   kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                  Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                                                     at com.example.ruiru.salestracker.AddSales.onCreate(AddSales.kt:25)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: date!!.setText("15-11-2017") date you declared as null. and you are setting text to null variable. Set text after initialise the view date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to initialize `date` editText. Why not to try [Kotlin Android Extension plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html). By using this plugin you don't need to initialize the views instead you can directly use them using their id. For your case:
Just add import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_sales.*
```

Then you can now remove your:

```
val date: EditText? = null
val changeDate: CheckBox? = null
val yes: RadioButton? = null
val no: RadioButton? = null
```

and you can access them by their ids. like

```
date.setText("15-11-2017")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your date EditText is null.Before use editText initialise editText like this

```
var date = findViewById<View>(R.id.date) as? EditText
```

then set the value of date

```
date?.setText("15-11-2017")
date?.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your EditText is null. You can initialize your EditText. Example Kotlin code,

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sales)

    val date = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDate)
    date.apply {
        setText("15-11-2017")
        isEnabled = false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val date: EditText? = null
val changeDate: CheckBox? = null
val yes: RadioButton? = null
val no: RadioButton? = null
```

Before using these variables, initialize them with `findViewById` or bind them to the xml view.